# Using python to run bash commands and get Output

Tags: python, linux, bash, youtube, download

I want to download videos through Youtube-he. So,I wrote program but it isn't working.The code is

```
import os
l=["sets","relation_and_functions","Trig","Complex_Quad","Linear_inequalities","Permutation","Binomial","Sequence","Straight","conic","Three_d","Limit_Derivative","Stats","Probability","Math_reasoning"]
r=["https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD5EF274490578CC4","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL548FAD237A4B6D2E","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL42123C3873AED16F","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL880E3116D67E42FD","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC5D1199BAE318878","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL812413BD6B55AA6E","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL78FAFAFA8496BCE1","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6F57725E2DA8B557","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA243228EA688A835","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL41B47FB4E23B392A","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa2X112u1cdjdl-dsLJC1HaCeGrOarZZz","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF6640F0A9F39F7BA","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6FDE1AB3AE32E614","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7FF5AD1CFF0981E5","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL13B63CD6FFAB9EA8"]
for i in range(len(l)):
    a=l[i]
    b=r[i]
    os.system("mkdir a")
    os.chdir("a")
    os.system("youtube-dl b")
```

Comment: `a` and `b` in those commands are string literals not your variables. Also this would create nested directories (as you never `cd` back up`)... that is if it worked but each `os.system` is a separate shell so the `cd` doesn't actually affect anything.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake and thanks for correcting me. I have posted a new code below which works properly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import os
l=["sets","relation_and_functions","Trig","Complex_Quad","Linear_inequalities","Permutation","Binomial","Sequence","Straight","conic","Three_d","Limit_Derivative","Stats","Probability","Math_reasoning"]
r=["https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD5EF274490578CC4","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL548FAD237A4B6D2E","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL42123C3873AED16F","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL880E3116D67E42FD","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC5D1199BAE318878","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL812413BD6B55AA6E","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL78FAFAFA8496BCE1","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6F57725E2DA8B557","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA243228EA688A835","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL41B47FB4E23B392A","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa2X112u1cdjdl-dsLJC1HaCeGrOarZZz","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF6640F0A9F39F7BA","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6FDE1AB3AE32E614","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7FF5AD1CFF0981E5","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL13B63CD6FFAB9EA8"]
c=[]
for i in l:
    c.append(i)
print c
for i in range(len(l)):
    q="mkdir "+l[i]
    l[i]=q
for j in range(len(r)):
    z="youtube-dl "+r[j]
    r[j]=z
print c
for i in range(len(l)):
    a=l[i]
    e=c[i]
    b=r[i]
    os.system(a)
    os.chdir(e)
    os.system(b)
    os.chdir("..")
```

This semmed to work properly.
Thank you. Guys for your help

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the actual variables, not a string. You should also use the subprocess module in particular [check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call):

```
l =["sets","relation_and_functions","Trig","Complex_Quad","Linear_inequalities","Permutation","Binomial","Sequence","Straight","conic","Three_d","Limit_Derivative","Stats","Probability","Math_reasoning"]
r=["https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD5EF274490578CC4","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL548FAD237A4B6D2E","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL42123C3873AED16F","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL880E3116D67E42FD","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC5D1199BAE318878","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL812413BD6B55AA6E","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL78FAFAFA8496BCE1","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6F57725E2DA8B557","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA243228EA688A835","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL41B47FB4E23B392A","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLa2X112u1cdjdl-dsLJC1HaCeGrOarZZz","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLF6640F0A9F39F7BA","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6FDE1AB3AE32E614","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL7FF5AD1CFF0981E5","https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL13B63CD6FFAB9EA8"]

from subprocess import check_call

for direc, url in zip(l, r):
     check_call(["mkdir", direc])
     check_call(["youtube-dl", ele2],cwd=direc)
```

`zip(l, r)` zips the corresponding elements from each list so we simply unpack the pairs in the loop. `cwd=direc` will set the directory to download the file to.

Comment: The call to `mkdir` should really be a call to `os.mkdir()`. Don't call out to external processes for things you could easily do yourself.

Comment: Efficiency, mostly. This will spawn a new process, `os.mkdir()` will not.

Comment: I just tested with `timeit` and got a 10776% difference between them (20.74 seconds vs 0.19 seconds to do it 10000 times). It won't be noticeable if you're only doing it once, but it's a _really_ bad habit to get into.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use `os.system("mkdir a")`, but `os.system("mdkir %s" % a)` because otherwise, it creates a directory called a. Variable names in strings are not evaluated. By the same reason, use `os.system("youtube-dl %s" % b)`. Additionally, use `os.system("cd a")` to change to the created directory and do not forget to change back by using `os.system("cd ..")` after that.